# PIC18F4520 reading voltage from analog input

Tags: voltage, pic, adc, proteus, mplabx

I'm trying to do a homework where is needed to read the voltage from an analog input and to print to a serial monitor a message when the voltage is lower than 2V or higher than 4V. I don't have any experience with PIC but I did what I found on internet.
Currently I'm trying to simulate this with proteus and mplabx.

```
float ADCvalue = 0;
float voltage = 0;

init_uart(9600);

while(1){
     __delay_us(10);        // Wait
    ADCON0bits.GO = 1;      // Start ADC conversion
    while(!ADCON0bits.GO);  // Wait for the conversion to complete
    PIR1bits.ADIF = 0;      // Clear ADIF Flag
    ADCvalue = ADRES;
    
    voltage = ?? 
    printf("Voltage= %d \r\n", voltage);
    
    Nop();
    __delay_ms(10);
}
```

Simulating it with a potentiometer, at 5V, ADCvalue seems to be -32768 and I don't know how to convert it to voltage..

Here is my simulation:
[image]

Comment: declare `voltage` as an unsigned integer

Comment: Use unsigned short, and you have to multiply it with the resolution.

Comment: You're printing a float with the %d specifier. Undefined behavior.

Comment: I don't see any code that turns the converter on -- `ADCON0.ADON = 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the datasheet, *"This module allows conversion of an analog
input signal to a corresponding 10-bit digital number"*
So the variable that reads the register needs to be of the same data type.
Here `ADCvalue = ADRES;` ADCValue should be an 16 bit unsigned type (`unsigned short` or `uint16`) , you currently have is as a `float`.

Also, you read the value into ADCvalue, then print `voltage` without an assignment into `voltage`.  First step is getting your A2D value to print.
Once you have that done you simply need to do the ratio of 10bits of data to your maximum input voltage and multiply that by your reading to get the current voltage value.

Comment: I declared ADCvalue as unsigned short and apply this ration: voltage = (ADCvalue * 5.0) / 1023; where 5.0 is maximum voltage. It works, thanks!!

Comment: @Oprisor To be pedantic, it has to be 1024.

Answer (score 1):

There are three registers which configure the ADC in the PIC18F: `ADCON0`, `ADCON1` and `ADCON2`.

A complete description of these registers may be found in section 19 (page 223) of the [PIC18F4520 datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39631E.pdf).

The ones I would make sure are set correctly are:

`ADCON0.ADON` -- this enables/disables the A/D converter module; make sure this bit is set to `1`

`ADCON1.PCFG` -- this configures which port pins are analog inputs; if it is set to `0b111`1 then `AN0` will be a digital input, not an analog input

`ADCON2.ADFM` -- this controls if the result is left or right justified; you probably want it to be right justified; the power-on default is left justified. See [this SE answer](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/a/3960) for an explanation of left vs. right justified numbers.